# Finding the Laplace transform of $f(x)=|\cos(x)|$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have function $f(x)=|\cos(x)|, x≥0$ and like to derive its Laplace transform. I am told that $f(x+\pi)=f(x)$. Help me please.

Comment: If you just need the result without derivation: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace+transform+abs%28cos%28x%29%29

Comment: I see there is a formula for your function.

Comment: @in_wolfram_we_trust: Make me a detailed hint.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have one.

Comment: But You can look at @BabakSorouh answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is periodic ($T=\pi$) so you can easily use the formula:

> $L(f(x))=\frac{1}{1-e^{-sT}}\int_{0}^{T}e^{-sT}f(x)dx$

Note that your function is a piecewise function broken at $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Nice!! :+) $\quad +1 \quad$